# Can I undo the last commit pushed to github with only tortoisehg and hg-git installed?

Tags: github, mercurial, hg-git

I can't seem to find a way to do it. I tried for example:

```
hg push -f git+ssh://git@github.com:greatwolf/testrepo.git
```

but it would just abort with:

> abort: refs/heads/master changed on the server, please pull and merge before pushing

Looking through the github web interface, there doesn't appear to be any `strip` command like in bitbucket. How can I nuke the last changeset committed without needing to install a git client on my working machine?

Right now the solution I'm thinking of is to just delete the repo from github, remake it and then push my local repo up. That'll work but it's more of a 'brute-force' kind of approach so I'd consider it as a last resort.

Comment: I hope you understand implications of deleting commits from public repos.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* try fiddling with the bookmarks in the local repo. If you change the master bookmark to point to the correct cset, hg-git might be smart enough to propagate that change into the git-side refs. Otherwise, I think this is a bit much too ask from hg-git, so chances are that you have to revert to your brute-force approach.